# Upgraded from Exchange 2007 to 2013, Redirect rules now AutoForwarding instead?

Tags: exchange, outlook, exchange-2013

We recently upgraded from Exchage 2007 to 2013 and I've had a number of rules setup through Outlook 2010 on my account so that when message arrive from specific email addresses and those messages are sent only to me, they are redirected to myself, and two other people in my office.

This is how the rule is setup in Outlook:

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
  sent only to me
    and from [example@server.com]
  redirect it to [Me] and [Coworker #1] and [Coworker #2]
    and delete it
```

When running Exchange 2007, the end result was that me, coworker # 1, and coworker # 2 would all get one email that looks like it was sent to all three of us instead of just me.

With Exchange 2013 what happens is that I receive a message that is addressed only to me with a notice in Outlook above the headers that says "This message was AutoForwarded", and my coworkers receive the email and it is only addressed to me as if they were BCC'd on the email.

What do I need to do to get the Exchange 2007 functionality back of adding the recipients' emails in the "To:" header?
I've tried launching outlook with /cleanrules and adding the rules back in but I still get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out an alternative, although it may not be the cleanest way.

I've created a new mailbox and using Exchange Admin Center added a new mail flow rule:

```
Apply this rule if ... 
  The recipient is "inneroffice"
Do the following ...
  Remove this header "To"
  Add these recipients to the To box [Myself] and [Coworker #1] and [Coworker #2]
```

And then in the Inneroffice mailbox I added a rule just to delete any incoming emails so that mailbox doesn't get filled.

Doing this gets me the results I wanted, I can forward emails to "inneroffice" and it'll get sent to all three of us and we are all visible in the "To" field.